# Magento 1.9.2.2 category display caching behaviour

Tags: magento

I updated my store to Magento 1.9.2.2 and now my categories do not work as expected.

`Example:` I have 3 categories A, B and C. Now, when I click on A, it shows the content of A. When I click on B, the title of the page in the browser tab and the URL changes but the content from A is still shown. Same with category C.

When I clear the cache it works once. The category I click first after clearing the cache is the one that gets shown except for the title in the browser tab and the URL.

I figured that disabling the `Blocks HTML output` cache solves the problem, but that can not be a solution. Any ideas what the problem is?

Thanks!

I tried what they sat at https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/83027/blocks-html-cache-sub-category-display without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a block is cahced there are keys that are associated.
In your case category id key that should have been associated is missed resulting in cached block for a given category page considered as a cache block for another category.

In short make sure to associate with the block category id as a key.

Comment: Thanks for helping, how would I achieve that? I updated my post with what I have tried without success.

Comment: /**
     * Get Key pieces for caching block content
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getCacheKeyInfo()
    {  is the function code in block class where you will have to add key as stated in My above comment.